# PL/SQL Developer: joining VARCHAR2 to NUMBER?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's where I am:

- `TABLE1.ITM_CD` is VARCHAR2 datatype
- `TABLE2.ITM_CD` is NUMBER  datatype
- Executing `left join TABLE2 on TABLE1.ITM_CD = TABLE2.ITM_CD` yields **ORA-01722: invalid number** error
- Executing `left join TABLE2 on to_number(TABLE1.ITM_CD) = TABLE2.ITM_CD` also yields **ORA-01722: invalid number** error.
  -- I suspect this is because one of the values in `TABLE1.ITM_CD` is the string "MIXED"
- Executing `left join TABLE2 on TABLE1.ITM_CD = to_char(TABLE2.ITM_CD)` successfully runs, but it returns blank values for the fields selected from `TABLE2`.

Here is a simplified version of my working query:

```
select
A.ITM_CD
,B.COST
,B.SIZE
,B.DESCRIPTION
,A.HOLD_REASON

from
TABLE1 a
left join TABLE2 b on a.ITM_CD = to_char(b.ITM_CD)
```

This query returns a list of item codes and hold reasons, but just blank values for the cost, size, and descriptions.   And I did confirm that `TABLE2` contains values for these fields for the returned codes.

**UPDATE:**  Here are pictures with additional info.

I selected the following info from `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`--I don't necessarily know what all fields mean, but thought it might be helpful

[image: Information]

**TABLE1** sample data
[image: TABLE1 image]

**TABLE2** sample data
[image: TABLE2 image]

Comment: Could you show in the questin a sample of numbers stored in the TABLE1 table ? What is format of these numbers ? Do they have a decimal point ?

Comment: Updated with sample--and neither contain decimals.

Comment: why not do a to_number instead?

Comment: Those leading zeros in TABLE1 look troubling.

Comment: @access_granted see 4th bullet on the top of my post

Comment: Run: `select * from table2 where regexp_like( d_itemcd, '[^0-9 ]' )` this will show wrong numbers stored in the table (records containing letters and characters other than digits and spaces).

Comment: can you assign 'mixed' a conversion null value or you suspect there will be more non-numeric string entries in table1?

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer? If you did, what was the result? A performance comparison against the accepted answer will be interesting, too - my answer doesn't need a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `TABLE1.ITM_CD` to a number after you strip any leading zeros and filter out the "MIXED" values:

```
select A.ITM_CD
      ,B.COST
      ,B.SIZE
      ,B.DESCRIPTION
      ,A.HOLD_REASON
from  ( SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ITM_CD <> 'MIXED' ) a
      left join TABLE2 b
      on TO_NUMBER( LTRIM( a.ITM_CD, '0' ) ) = b.ITM_CD
```

Comment: Unlikely to work - the OP stated that a.ITM_CD contains values like 'MIXED'.

Comment: OK, I see you added a condition to exclude 'MIXED' - perhaps it would be better to exclude anything that will not resolve to a number, like 'NA' or who knows what. If they allowed 'MIXED' the odds are greater than zero that there may also be other non-numeric values.

Comment: "MIXED" is the only non-numeric value I see, even after running kordirko's query.  But this still does not work--it executes, fetches exactly 1500 records, then I get the same ORA-01722 error, then all fetched records disappear and I'm left with a blank page.

Comment: If it will always have a leading zero of "numeric" values then you can do `WHERE ITM_CD LIKE '0%'` to try to filter what to include rather than what to exclude. Or you can invert it to see what is causing errors: `SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ITM_CD NOT LIKE '0%'`. (Also, who is kordirko and which query of his?)

Comment: You can try to find all the non-numeric values in your table with the query kordirko suggested in a comment to your question. You may have spaces or who knows what.

Comment: @MT0 knowing all codes are 6 digits or fewer, I substituted your `<> 'MIXED'` for `<= '999999'` and it works successfully.  Thanks so much for the assistance.  Also, this is the query I was referencing: `select * from table2 where regexp_like( d_itemcd, '[^0-9 ]' )`

Answer (score 0):

This is a SQL (and really a database) problem, not PL/SQL. You will need to fix this - fight your bosses if you have to. Item code must be a Primary Key in one of your two tables, and a Foreign Key in the other table, pointing to the PK. Or perhaps Item code is PK in another table which you didn't show us, and Item code in both the tables you showed us should be FK pointing to that PK.

You don't have that arrangement now, which is exactly why you are having all this trouble. The data type must match (it doesn't now), and you shouldn't have values like 'MIXED' - unless your business rules allow it, and then the field should be VARCHAR2 and 'MIXED' should be one of the values in the PK column (whichever table that is in).

In your case, the problem is that the codes in VARCHAR2 format start with a leading 0, so if you compare to the numbers converted to strings, you never get a match (and in the outer join, the match is always assumed to be to NULL).

Instead, when you convert your numbers to strings, add leading zero(s) like this:

```
...on a.ITM_CD = TO_CHAR(b.ITM_CD, '099999')
```

Comment: The query functions with this, but returns no values for the fields from TABLE2--an identical result to what I describe in my 5th bullet. To your other point, the value 'MIXED' is apparently used when there are multiple item codes on one pallet.  This database is housed in a company we recently acquired, so I'm not nearly as familiar with its conventions as I should be.

Comment: This means a.ITM_CD still doesn't match the number from b.ITM_CD, changed to string and with 0 pre-pended.  Are you sure the strings in the ITM_CD column in TABLE1 don't contain spaces as well? (Easy to find out - for example "select ITM_CD from TABLE1 WHERE LENGTH(ITM_CD) <> 6). If I am reading ALL_TAB_COLUMNS correctly it seems ALL your ITM_CD's in TABLE1 are length 8.

Comment: You're correct, there are two spaces after the 6 digit value.  Earlier I pasted these codes into Excel, and Excel automatically formatted them as numbers, so I assumed no spaces or other characters.  But just now, I concatenated the item code value with a date value, and sure enough, there are two spaces between the two.

Comment: This is why the other solutions weren't working either, then. They were just trimming the 0 from the left, but not the spaces. You can try my solution, where the only change to b.ITM_CD, instead of what I showed, is TO_CHAR(b.ITM_CD, '099999') || '  '    After the concatenation operator || you have TWO SPACES between single-quotes. This is almost the same as your very first query, and it should work. It may also be quite a bit faster than the other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can trim leading zeros from your string column.

`select
    A.ITM_CD
    ,B.COST
    ,B.SIZE
    ,B.DESCRIPTION
    ,A.HOLD_REASON
    from
    TABLE1 a
    left join TABLE2 b on trim(LEADING '0' FROM a.ITM_CD ) = to_char(b.ITM_CD)`

Comment: This will work, but since you are using to_char on b.ITM_CD, why not add the zero(s) there, with a format mask?